# unable to get $_REQUEST value in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, restful-url

I'm trying to create a restful api the only problem is that I'm unable to get $_REQUEST value. the same code work fine on localhost but not on to server. This is probably happen due to my htaccess code. When api call by url `processApi` is the function that is called and find out which function of this api is called by url

For example 
http://www.domain.com/file.php/api/test

Now I'm trying to call `test` function that is in `api` class

htaccess code redirect my url

The first function inside `api` class is `processApi` that check wether test function exist or not

But inside `processApi` function $_REQUEST value is null

This is happen on server but on localhost it work fine

This is htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ file.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ file.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ file.php [QSA,NC,L]  

</IfModule>
```

This is the api code

```
class API extends REST 
{               
    private $db = NULL;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function processApi()
    {
       $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("api/","",$_REQUEST['request'])));

        if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0)
        {   
                  $this->$func();  
        }
        else
        {            
                $error = array('status' => '402', "msg" => 'function not exist');
                $this->response($this->json($error), 402);
        }
     } 
  }

  $api = new API;
  $api->processApi();
```

By running this code onto server i got

```
{"status":"402","msg":"function not exist"}
```

Just because $_REQUEST['request'] is null

Please point me why I'm get `$_REQUEST['request']` = null. Is my htaccess code giving right value in `$_REQUEST['request']`

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($func)`? If it should be `test` as you expect, then why don't you have function `test` in your API class?

Comment: Also, remember that PHP does not have native support for things like PUT or DELETE requests. In order to get her the data you would need to call `parse_str (file_get_contents('php://input') , $_DATA)` and that would put any data passed to the server in the $_DATA variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be looking at PHP's `$_SERVER` variable instead of `$_REQUEST`.

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] should give you the correct URI for /api/test
```

Running `var_dump` on $_SERVER gives you more information about the current request (and the server environment that is processing it)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

That is probably happening due to your last rule that runs after your first rule. Change your code like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # skip after rewriting first time
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ file.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule . file.php [L]  

</IfModule>
```

Comment: firstly thank you for your answer but unfortunately after changing `htaccess` code with your code i am still getting `$_REQUEST['request']`  null in `processApi()` function

Comment: rename your file.php to something else and create a new file.php with this code: `<?php print_r($_GET); ?>` and tell me what it prints